# DBConnect Error processing sql:undefined when insert with date and time in SQLite

Tags: cordova, sqlite

How to store date and time in an SQLite database with Phonegap? I tried to use Datatype as "NUMERIC" and insert query with DATETIME('now'). But I got an error: "DBConnect Error processing sql:undefined".

What is the best way to store date and time in SQLite database using Phonegap? Also I need to sort by date and time in this table.

Comment: please anyone can answer my questions?

Comment: If i use VarChar for date and time, is it possible to query order by date and time?

Comment: yes, internal representation should be 2012-08-31 hh:mm:ss . So Select * from x ORDER BY dt DESC   would be newest first

Comment: Thank you. I have done this with cdatetime VARCHAR DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.This inserted current date and time by default.

Comment: Sure.please add in answer box

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html has some helpful functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime-columns should be created as `varchar(40)` 
(and not numeric like in e.g. Access)

internal representation is 2012-08-31 hh:mm:ss.

So `Select * from x ORDER BY dt DESC` would be newest first